# Performing A Controller Push Hangs App

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I've a `ViewController` where I `Crop Image`, and then another where I `Filter Images` which means I've to transfer the cropped data to the filter section. But, I don't get any error. Just that my debugger hangs on that line of code until I step out and still nothing happens

```
internal func moveToFilter() {
    var cropFrame = cropOverlay.frame
    cropFrame.origin.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    cropFrame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if let i = image {
        let croppedImage = i.crop(cropFrame, scale: scrollView.zoomScale)
        print(croppedImage)
        let confirmViewCamera = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("filterPhoto") as! FilterViewController <-- This is where it hangs
        confirmViewCamera.imageToFilter = croppedImage
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(confirmViewCamera, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have probably turned breakpoints on and you app is crashing. It's probably crashing either because there is no view controller with such an identifier in your storyboard or it is not a `FilterViewController`.

Comment: @HAS you see, I'm totally confused at the moment. Cause I've tried to log, and put line breaks and and all. It's like as if FilterViewController can't be seen. But, then it'll at least get to where it'll present and throw the error. Instead, it halts on that line. Just that line. No line breaks, no nothing

Comment: I've checked my story board, my identifier id, the class attached to the viewcontroller. Nothing

Comment: So just to recap: the reuse identifier of the view controller(!) is "filterPhoto" and the class of the same view controller is `FilterViewController`?

Comment: @HAS The `controller` this code is being ran is a `controller` initialized using a `Xib file` so, I decided to rewrite my code and have the filter a `Storyboard` view. And all was working fine. It was name changing that got me to doing that conflicting name thing

Comment: Glad to hear it's working :) Great (y)